# HOW TO : C# split string to multidimensional array for filling it to datagridview

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, split, datagridview

I have to fill my datagridview from string that have delimiter "~" for rows then "|" for columns in each row

my datagridview columns : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/821Kb.png)

example string below

```cs
string ShoppingDetail = "Gas LPG 5Kg|6 pcs|30.000 x 6|2.000 x 6|168.000~Gas LPG 12Kg|10 pcs|40.000 x 10|2.000 x 10|380.000";
```

i want to fill datagridview from above string

my code

```cs
                var data = ShoppingDetail.Split('~').Select(x => x.Split('|')).ToArray();
                int height = data.GetLength(0);
                int width = data.GetLength(1);

                //this.DtDetail.ColumnCount = width;

                for (int r = 0; r < height; r++)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                    row.CreateCells(this.DataGridDetails);

                    for (int c = 0; c < width; c++)
                    {
                        row.Cells[c].Value = data[r][c];
                    }

                    this.DataGridDetails.Rows.Add(row);
                }
```

Comment: Gridview are really designed to bind to external data sources, why not use the Table control?

Comment: im sorry i forgot to describe if this is a windows form application. this is windows form application so there is no table control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way, no need to complicate stuff IMHO:

```
var data = ShoppingDetail.Split("~");
            for (int r = 0; r < data.Length; r++)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                row.CreateCells(this.DataGridDetails);
                var cells = data[r].Split("|");
                for (int c = 0; c < cells.Length; c++)
                {
                    row.Cells[c].Value = cells[c];
                }

                this.DataGridDetails.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

Comment: i changed it little bit. thanks its worked!

Comment: @MuhammadAufaRijal you can mark my answer as "answer" if you think it helped :)